# C# Entity LINQ returns wrong and duplicate values

Tags: c#, linq, entity

I use the following code :

```
List<vw_GetIMeasurements> Imeasurements = context.vw_GetIMeasurements.Where(f => f.MEMBERID == userID).Distinct().ToList();
```

This returns a list with 12 Values like it should but these values are always the same(even though they aren't in the DB.(Even if they were distinct should solve this)

[image: Visual of the issue]

DB :

[image: Database Image]

The raw value that is returned is also wrong.
What would be the cause of this issue and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Does `vw_GetIMeasurements` implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode`?

Comment: Can you provide some testdata please?

Comment: Yes, it does implement those.

Comment: Distinct uses the Default Equality Comparer (at least I believe that)

Comment: Your backing view has something wrong with it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have had this problem before - it turned out that the view did not have unique `entity keys` set - make sure your primary keys for your view that is auto created by entity framework is indeed unique...

Comment: I can't change the Database, is there any other way to make this happen?

Comment: You dont to need change the database - its the model (.edmx file) in your designer, make sure the entity keys are unique enough, the EF will try to create a unique key but it doesnt always get it right for views.

Comment: The issue is that all of these values aren't unique , so they always appear multipel times. I think I can solve the issue I have by Selecting the 2 colums that I need and not the entire row.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue - the database view looked fine in SQL server but when debugging, duplicate rows were appearing where rows shared a particular attribute value.

I found that one of the important unique keys was from a outer join table - therefore had the potential to be null - and the model was not assigning as unique.

I was able to fix this problem by setting this field to ISNULL(field, '') - ensuring that a value is always returned - and upon updating, the model correctly interprets the field as unique and as part of a compound key and the rows returned correctly.

I know that one might argue the view design is at fault (i.e. I should not be using an outer join), but in this instance, there was a specific need for the outer join. The fix works because the compound key is still unique even if "" is returned multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a more simple syntax like this

```
var measure = from f in context.vw_GetIMeasurements
              where  f.MEMBERID == userID
              select f;
```

This kind of thing is working for me..

Comment: Well I'm trying to get back a list of multiple values. How would this be done?

Comment: This kind of linq request return an IENUMERABLE<T>. You can Apply a .Tolist() after that to get a List<T>

Comment: Sadly enough this gives the sames values as in the question. EVen the raw value is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is infact what Richard described. However I was unable to choose a correct "Unique Key" so this caused more issue.

I solved my problem by creating a custom made class and creating this in SQL. I also limited my Select to 2 of the 3 Columns.

```
List<Measurement> result = (from f in context.vw_GetIMeasurements where f.MEMBERID == userID select new Measurement { Category = f.atcmCATEGORYCODEID, Size = f.imMeasurementNumber }).ToList();
```

Measurement is in the case the self made Class.